# PHP redirect buttons in DataTables are not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatables

I'm generating a table using PHP that will retrieve records from a MySQL database. I'm new to DataTables, and my problem is that the "View Products" button that generates along with the table doesn't work. Clicking the button should redirect to a new page with an entirely different table.

[here's a screenshot of what it looks like, just in case I'm not making any sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5pw9.png)

Here's the entire code for the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\WEBDEV\css\reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\WEBDEV\css\stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\WEBDEV\css\og_stylesheet.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    thead {
      background-color: #dc3545;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- HEADER -->
  <?php include "includes/header.php" ?>

  <?php session_start();

?>
  <!-- END HEADER -->

            <table class="table table-striped" id="table_id">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Supplier ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Contact Number</th>
                    <th>Supplier Details</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "web_db");
                      $query = "SELECT * FROM Suppliers";
                      $search = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($search) > 0 ){
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search)){
                          ?>
                    <form action="supplierdetails.php" method="POST">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <?= $row['supplier_id']?>
                        </td>
                        <input type="hidden" value=< ?=$row[ 'supplier_id']?> name = "sup_id">
                        <input type="hidden" value=< ?=$row[ 'name']?> name = "name">
                        <td>
                          <?= $row['name']?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <?= $row['address']?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <?= $row['contactnumber']?>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="View Products" class="btn btn-info" onclick="sample()"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                          }
                        }
                      ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".alert").delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    function sample() {
      window.alert(document.getElementById("name").getAttribute("value"));
    }
  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/DataTables/datatables.js"></script>-->


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#table_id').DataTable();
    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dataTables.filter.range.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();

      /* Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs */
      $('#min, #max').keyup(function() {
        table.draw();
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The buttons work perfectly before I added DataTables, by the way. I also found out that a table with hard-coded data (as in without PHP) also have buttons that work fine. I'm pretty much at my wits end here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show the sample function.Also any console errors?

Comment: there aren't any console errors. it just simply doesn't work when clicked. no feedback whatsoever. also, sorry, but can you clarify what you mean by sample function? i'm assuming you meant the query used to retrieve the data from the database. i didn't use any function since the query is only SELECT. i'll edit my post and just put the entire code so it makes more sense. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: onclick="sample()" This sample function

Comment: oh, okay. it should be this: function sample() {
      window.alert(document.getElementById("name").getAttribute("value"));
    }

Comment: i also just updated my original post so the whole code is included. at least the ones i think mattered. i got rid of the navigation bar and side bar so they don't clog up the post. hopefully this would clarify some things

Comment: The problem is most likely the rendering queue. Datatables cant render the your function sample() inside the table.  Why not simply call the url from your table perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick="sample()"`
Add this in a document.ready

```
$(".btn-info").on("click", function() {
    window.alert(document.getElementById("name").getAttribute("value"));
});
```

Maybe use a `window.alert('test');`
since I dont see the element with the id name anywhere

Comment: tried it, and it's still unresponsive. i'm starting to think it might have something to do with the PHP code itself... i appreciate the help, though